# search comma separated values from column contains comma separated string mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to search comma separated values from database table column contains comma separated string.

```
MY DB

id    interest    status
------------------------
1      1,2,3        1
2        4          1
```

My search combination contains `1,2`, `3,2`, `3`, `1,4` etc. Any combination will occure.

I want to show all the `id` that contains any digit from comma separated search combination.

For example, search for `1,4` should return

```
id
--
1
2
```

For example, search for `3,2` should return

```
id
--
1
```

I have tried using `IN` and `FIND_IN_SET` but none of them achieved my result. Is there any other option.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_test` WHERE interest IN (3)
```

The above code return empty set.

Comment: Do not store values as csv. Normalize your database.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET helps you to search for only one element in a given set, so searching for multiple elements like '1,2' will have be chained using AND operator. It might get messy when you have to look for more than 2 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jens has pointed out in the comments, it is **highly recommended** to normalize your schema.

If you wish to continue with string and comma separated values, you should then be looking at ***complex regex matching*** (which I leave it to you to explore).

However, one more alternative is to convert your column `interest` as **JSON** datatype. **MYSQL 5.7** and above supports these datatypes.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `interest`  JSON DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl` (`id`, `interest`,`status`) VALUES
  (1, '[1,2,3,4]',1),
  (2, '[1,2]',1),
  (3, '[3]',1);
```

And then query it as follows :

```
select id from tbl where JSON_CONTAINS( interest ,'[1,2]')
select id from tbl where JSON_CONTAINS( interest ,'[3,4]');
...
```

You can see it action in [this sql fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t4quzPNpw9Ezg6R2jqFjb2/0)